# docker-compose on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, amazon-ecs

I would like an web a software on AWS. Locally, I run it on Ubuntu VirtualBox VM with docker-compose, it requires 2-4 cores, 8G RAM, 30-40G disk. Do you think it will run on AWSS? Should I install docker-compose and app on a EC2?  Elasticbean, ECS, (https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/06/amazon-ecs-cli-supports-docker-compose-version-3/ ), or something else?

I am vary because my attempts to run it on an IT department managed KVM failed.

What resources are best to request for either of solutions?

At the moment it is more of prove of concept/demo, but eventually I hope deploying production on a Kubernetes cluster

I'm looking for, in the order of decreasing importance :

1. Simplicity and chances to succeed with deployment asap
2. costs
3. stability, QoS

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using [AWS Fargate](https://aws.amazon.com/fargate/). This lets you run container-based applications without having to managing the underlying EC2 instance. You can use Fargate with either ECS or EKS.

The ECS CLI that you link to in your question also helps you create your application and should make it easy get started.

You can look at [ecsworkshop.com](https://ecsworkshop.com/) for an introduction to using ECS and Fargate.